# Why does u-substitution contain derivative of g(x)

Tags: integration, substitution

I'm trying to honestly trying to understand why the Jacobian is present in the change of variable in double integrals and hit a brick wall when trying to do the same for single integrals(ofc u-substitution).

$\int f(x)dx$ and after the u-substitution gives $\int f(g(x))g'(x)dx$ and of course the bounds changed if they were present.

My question is, what is the geometric interpretation of the derivative.

My thinking: Since the substitution in general, changed the original area by stretching or squishing it, this is meant to somehow undo that change but I don't see how a derivative would do that.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $dx$ in the new integral?

Comment: Analyse the case when $g(x)=ax$ for some $a$, to understand why in the case of a linear change of variable, the derivative naturally comes in. Then think about a general differentiable function as being "almost linear" when the variable is changed just a little bit.

Comment: That is honestly a very interesting way to think about it. Thank you

Comment: Also ya it should be a dx, ty fixed it